# SCSI controller vs RAID controller

Tags: raid, scsi, controller

I have a Poweredge server which has a Ultra 160 SCSI controller, I was wondering if this has the ability to set the drives as RAID1 or 5?

Is a SCSI & RAID controller generally the same thing?

Comment: Which server model are you referring to? How old is the system? Those details are important because they will determine what's possible with your hardware setup.

Answer (score 1):

No, a SCSI controller and a RAID controller are different, although *some* SCSI controllers can have basic RAID functionality. Raw Ultra 160 SCSI drives were phased-out beginning in 2002. Are you dealing with an extremely old system?

Generally, there are a few terms to explain.

[SCSI is a protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCSI), but can also describe type of drives. Your mention of Ultra 160 describes a generation of *[parallel SCSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCSI#Parallel_SCSI)* technology.

Since SCSI is a protocol, you can have single SCSI disks or other devices like tape drives that communicate via SCSI. Typically, the interface will be a SCSI controller/adapter.

RAID controllers add RAID logic, caching and logic to this equation...

But I'm just speculating on your setup. please provide more details about your server equipment.